# Is it possible to use share_xaxis for some specific subplots?

Tags: python, plotly

I use make_subplot for 3 rows and 1 columns, the first 2 rows are data plot and the last row is image. I’s like to use shared_xaxis for the first 2 data plot, how to do it by excluding the last row of image plot? Thanks

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, 
                vertical_spacing=0.05, 
                specs=[[{"secondary_y": False}],[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": False,"type": "image"}]],  #
                subplot_titles=(plot_title_1stsubplot,plot_title_2ndsubplot
                               ),
                row_heights=[0.7,0.15,0.15],
                shared_xaxes=False,
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that setting `shared_xaxes` (`shared_yaxes`) is a shortcut for setting a [`matches`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-matches) constraint between x (y) axes :

> `matches` - If set to another axis id (e.g. `x2`, `y`), the range of this axis
> will match the range of the corresponding axis in data-coordinates
> space. Moreover, matching axes share auto-range values, category lists
> and histogram auto-bins.

You can make the xaxis of the 2nd subplot (row 2) matches the xaxis of the first subplot (row 1) :

```py
fig.update_xaxes(row=2, matches='x')
```

Or the contrary :

```py
fig.update_xaxes(row=1, matches='x2')
```